# Android ImageView not always displaying pictures

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I want the user to be able to select a picture from a gallery. The selected picture should be then displayed in my `ImageView`. I found several different examples of how to do this, but with no success. Some of the pictures in picasa will be set to the `Imageview`, but if i select the same picture from the gallery, it is never displayed in the `ImageView`. I did some research and I have seen that some people were able to fix this by changing their layout, or by scaling their picture using the BitmapFactory. I have tried both of these, and these didn't work for me.

Please note that on my AVD everything runs smooth. On a real device it either crashes on selecting a picture, or the imageview is shown without any picture.
Here is my code:

```
private View.OnClickListener onUploadImage = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            uploadImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

And here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E6C4A8"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:context="com.example.weddingplanner.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/settingsBanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/settingsbanner" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:paddingLeft="10dp"
              android:paddingRight="10dp"
              android:paddingTop="10dp" >

              <com.example.weddingplanner.MyTextView
                  android:id="@+id/coupleNameTextView"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#000818"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="@string/couple_name"
                  android:textColor="#E6C4A8"
                  android:textSize="28sp"
                  customfontdemo:fontName="arabtype.ttf" />

              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal" >

                  <com.example.weddingplanner.MyTextView
                        android:id="@+id/welcomeLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/names"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        customfontdemo:fontName="arabtype.ttf"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/namesTextbox"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:ems="10"
                      android:inputType="textPersonName" />
              </LinearLayout>

              <com.example.weddingplanner.MyTextView
                  android:id="@+id/weddingDateLabel"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#000818"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="@string/wedding_date"
                  android:textColor="#E6C4A8"
                  android:textSize="28sp"
                  customfontdemo:fontName="arabtype.ttf" />

              <LinearLayout
                  android:id="@+id/welcomeLabel"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal" >

                  <com.example.weddingplanner.MyTextView
                        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/date"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        customfontdemo:fontName="arabtype.ttf"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                  <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/dateTextbox"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:ems="10"
                      android:inputType="date" >

                      <requestFocus />
                  </EditText>
              </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/uploadImage"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              android:layout_weight="0.49"
              android:src="@drawable/uploadpicturebutton" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <ImageButton
                  android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"
                  android:background="#E6C4A8"
                  android:paddingRight="5dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/savebutton" />

              <ImageButton
                  android:id="@+id/clearButton"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"
                  android:background="#E6C4A8"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/clearbutton" />

          </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When it crashes, what's the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's difficult to say exactly what the problem is without more details about the exception, I'd like to point out an inherent problem with your approach.

You're attempting to display the entire, raw image into your UI. I don't know how large those images images are, but keep your application's memory constraints in mind. If you're attempting to load a 8MP image into memory, you are consuming (for ARGB) 4 × 8 MB = 32 MB. Depending on your device, this may already consume the entire heap, and cause an OutOfMemoryException.

You mentioned that "using the BitmapFactory" didn't work for you. If you've used the BitmapFactory to load images in at a lower sample size, this could eliminate the memory problem.

I would instead avoid reinventing the wheel and use a library such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for loading images.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using picasso and it was to last piece to the puzzle. Cool stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Create Drawable Object from file path

Ex:
Drawable  d=Drawable.createFromPath(selectedImagePath);

uploadImage.setImageDrawable(d);

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the relevant permission in your manifest file? If not, add this and try:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it still crashes, please paste your logs also from logcat.. This'll help dig deeper into the real problem..

Comment: If this helped somewhat, at least 1 up vote can be given, if not acceptance.. :)

Comment: I would but i need 15 reputation for that :(

Comment: Oh is it..!! :) never mind.. M happy with the fact that I cud help.. There'll be more chances of getting upvotes.. :D